# Wiring DC motor with an encoder to an ESP32 controller

Tags: microcontroller, dc-motor, esp32

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to motorize the roller shades in my house using EspHome. I'm new to the DIY electronics space but have spent time learning as much as possible and I picked out the following components:

1. **JGY370** worm gear DC motor with encoder (12V)
2. **WT32-ETH01 controller** (Ethernet based ESP32)
3. **L298N motor driver**
4. **12V Power supply**

I've attempted drawing up the wiring but have run into a roadblock not knowing how to properly wire the encoder to the controller. Also wasn't sure if a buck converter is necessary? The motor supply voltage is 12V so thought the 5V regulator on the L298N can be enabled so i can use 5V pin as output to the WT32-ETH01 controller. Here's a rough diagram of what I had so far. Any help on correctly wiring this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do not connect it this way or you may fry the encoder! From https://www.robotics.org.za/JGY-370-ENC I learn that BLUE is the encoder supply and should be connected to your 5V rail instead!

Comment: Thanks heaps! Yeah definitely don't want to fry the encoder. So i can connect it to the 5v out on the motor driver? Also, do you think the GPIO pins used on the controller would work? Looking at the datasheet for the board I can't seem to figure out the correct pins

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @stdcerr For more clarification, looking at the datasheet for the WT32-ETH01 [here](https://files.seeedstudio.com/products/102991455/WT32-ETH01_datasheet_V1.1-%20en.pdf) I can't tell which pins are digital so that I can connect the encoder output pins (yellow,white)

Comment: @Kimeru it appears like IO 12 & IO35 should work fine as inputs per the datasheet you linked. You may want to connect it to an interupt but I can't tell from the datasheet you provided if that's an option on these pins (one of them is sufficient). Connect a pin to an interrupt for rising edge detection. On interrupt, check the other pin's state to determine motor direction and adjust the step counter accordingly.